# node.js application deployment in aws in CentOs not working

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, amazon-ec2, centos

when i run a node.js application in CentOs 6.5 in AWS

```
var sys = require( "sys" );
var http = require( "http" );
// Create our HTTP server.
var server = http.createServer(
function( request, response ){
// Create a SUPER SIMPLE response.
response.writeHead( 200, {"content-type": "text/plain"} );
response.write( "Hellow world from AWS!\n" );
response.end();
}
);
// Point the HTTP server to port 8080.
server.listen( 3000 );
// For logging....
console.log( "Server is running on 3000" );
```

it runs and shows this on console:
Server is running on 3000

but when i open my browser and run the 
public DNS given by amazon
:http://ec2-54-152-55-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/, it shows webpage not available ,but in terminal of CentOs in aws ,when I run command :curl  http://ec2-54-152-55-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/ it shows 
Hellow world from AWS!

1)Inbound rules are 
HTTP --                      AnyWhere
SSH  --                       AnyWhere
CUSTOM TCP RULE (PORT-3000)-- AnyWhere
HTTPS--                       AnyWhere
CUSTOM UDP RULE (PORT-3000)-- AnyWhere
2)Outbound Rules are 
All traffic| All protocol |ALL port| AnyWhere

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-1 THis might be helpful.

Comment: Try `server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0')`

Comment: tried "server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0')" @GauravGupta it is still not working

Comment: Hi @GauravGupta i followed the tutorial and executed the instruction step by step ,but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is resolved ,even setting inbound rules  as follows:
HTTP -- AnyWhere
SSH -- AnyWhere
CUSTOM TCP RULE (PORT-3000)-- AnyWhere
HTTPS-- AnyWhere
CUSTOM UDP RULE (PORT-3000)-- AnyWhere

in centOS 6.5 instance ,firewall was not allowing any connection from port (HTTP)80,(CUSTOM)3000,(HTTPS)443.Therefore,i made allow the required port no. in iptables
see:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/ to edit the iptables and restarted the firewall
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-basic-iptables-firewall-on-centos-6   to allow particular port in firewall